# Rails Date Picker (with jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datepicker

I would like to add a simple date picker to my form.

Is there something that built-in in Rails 3 or I should look for jQuery plugins ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also check out [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) that has a built-in date-picker as well as some other neat UI elements.  All easily customizable with CSS as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of datepickers available that are integrated into Rails via the "FormBuilders".

More details can be found here http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/DatePicker

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend jQuery UI's date picker plugin

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this one: https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker/
And it's very small, according to the README

There's also a gem for the datepicker: https://github.com/derencius/zebra-datepicker-rails
and it's working in Rails 4

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple plugin to integrate Rails and jQuery Datepicker (and datetime).

https://github.com/albertopq/jquery_datepicker

Regards